# How to move column data one column over with pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm reading some csv files which aren't well designed into a dataframe, and one attribute, Yes/No, can appear in either Col_B or Col_C, depending on a color attributes that exists or not

After the importing the CSV, the dataframe looks like this

```
        Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    Col_D
    0     One      Yes     True      NaN
    1     One      Yes     True      NaN
    2     One    Black      Yes     True
    3     One    Black      Yes     True
    4     One      Yes     True      NaN
    5     One      Yes     True      NaN
```

I need to move the values of rows 2 and 3 one column over to the left, for all the columns after Col_B, So the end result would look like this:
(I'v simplified the csv layout for this example)

```
        Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    Col_D
    0     One      Yes     True      NaN
    1     One      Yes     True      NaN
    2     One      Yes     True      Nan
    3     One      Yes     True      Nan
    4     One      Yes     True      NaN
    5     One      Yes     True      NaN
```

I can then remove Col_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all shifted indexes by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and then swap values in columns:

```
idx = df.index[df['Col_D'].notnull()]
df.loc[idx, ['Col_B','Col_C']] = df.loc[idx, ['Col_C','Col_D']].values
df = df.drop('Col_D', axis=1)
print (df)
  Col_A Col_B Col_C
0   One   Yes  True
1   One   Yes  True
2   One   Yes  True
3   One   Yes  True
4   One   Yes  True
5   One   Yes  True
```

Another solution with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), last remove column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
cols = ['Col_B','Col_C','Col_D']
idx = df.index[df['Col_D'].notnull()]
df.loc[idx, cols] = df.loc[idx, cols].shift(-1, axis=1)
df = df.drop('Col_D', axis=1)
print (df)
  Col_A Col_B Col_C
0   One   Yes  True
1   One   Yes  True
2   One   Yes  True
3   One   Yes  True
4   One   Yes  True
5   One   Yes  True
```

Comment: I used the 2nd method. Is there a way to asses which one is better optimized? I'm reading ~100 csv files with ~25K rows, cleaning them and appending them to a final dataframe.

Comment: I compare timings and output with `60k` rows -> `%timeit (a(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop`

`%timeit (b(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.52 ms per loop`

Comment: `df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)`

`cols = ['Col_B','Col_C','Col_D']`
`idx = df.index[df['Col_D'].notnull()]`

`def a(df):
    df.loc[idx, cols] = df.loc[idx, cols].shift(-1, axis=1)
    return df`

`def b(df):
    df.loc[idx, ['Col_B','Col_C']] = df.loc[idx, ['Col_C','Col_D']].values
    return df`